# matrix expression calculation

Tags: java, matrix

Could anybody, please, point me on the algorithm of how matrix multiplication can be done (Identifying the order of multiplying). I tried really different way which I could design, but nothing works as expected, unfortunately :( For example I have one of the following matrix chains to multiply:

```
((((0(((((((((((((((1 2)3)4)5)6)7)8)9)10)11)12)13)14)15)16))17)18)19 

((((((((((((0 1)2)3)4)5)6)7)8)9)10)(11(12(13(14(15(16(1718))))))))19

(((((0 1)(2(((3 4)(5 6))(((7 8)(9(10 11)))((((12 13)14)15)16)))))17)18)19  

(((((((0 1)2)3)4)5)(6(7(8(9(10(11(12 13))))))))(((((14 15)16)17)18)19)
```

Can somebody share a universal algorithm for all the cases?

NOTE:
1.I need multiplication only.
2.Matrices have different dimension, so they are not square. (Naturally, Matrices' dimensions agree)
3.Maybe [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769) can be helpful, but I really have no idea how it can be applied here.

Thanks in advance to everybody who is trying to help!

Comment: Doesn't any order work since matrices are associative and `(n x m)(m x p) = (n x p)`?

Comment: @irrelephant, yeah, you're right. But I'm implementing algorithms for optimal matrix chain multiplication, so, let's say, these chains are optimal ones for some matrices. The only thing I do not understand is how to multiply according to the order provided.

Comment: if the matrix is in nxm dim array it is pretty straight forward, could you explain what are the rows in the above format.

Comment: Ok I googled, excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Based on the link you posted to parsing, do you need help parsing/compiling this string of matrices?

Comment: @Willc. yes, this is exactly what I need. I need to parse some string similar to those I provided above and understand from them what is the order of matrices I need to multiply in accordance with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "Matrix chain multiplication".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication

Comment: I think OP knows that much.

Comment: No, maybe it is not clear for the topic, but I have an optimal matrix chain. I do not understand how to multiply in accordance with this optimal matrix chain.

Comment: So you do not understand how to multiply 2 matrices? Or what the order of multiplying the matrices is?